# GCC does not recognize escape character '\' on multi-line input

Tags: c, char, printf, conversion-specifier

The below will raise compilation warning `warning: unknown conversion type character ‘w’ in format [-Wformat=]`
on a new version of gcc: `gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0`

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main() {
    char query[4096];
    snprintf(query, sizeof(query), "SELECT e.expression_id, e.name, e.channel, e.subsidiary_of, ds.input_channel FROM expression e "
            " JOIN shoe s ON s.shoe_id = e.shoe_id JOIN device_serial ds ON s.device_id = ds.device_id " 
            "WHERE e.name NOT LIKE '\%walker\%' ORDER BY e.channel");
    printf("%s \n", query);
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine on a shorter input and also on older versions of gcc. How can I make it recognize the backslash as an escape character?

Comment: @Cheetaiean Either use "\\%%walker\\%%" or "%%walker%%"

Comment: I want to include `LIKE '%walker%'` in the char array. The slashes are to escape the percent symbol from being treated like a format string

Comment: To print a literal `%` sign you need to double it as in `"%%"`

Comment: thanks, the `%%` got rid of the compilation warning

Comment: I don't understand the point of calling snprintf when you aren't formatting any variables. That's just a very expensive string copy with extra escaping rules you don't need.

Comment: the query will be used to execute a PSQL command, I simplified the code for the purposes of the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write

```
"WHERE e.name NOT LIKE '%%walker%%' ORDER BY e.channel"
```

From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function)

> 8 The conversion specifiers and their meanings are:
>
> **%** A % character is written. No argument is converted. The complete conversion specification shall be %%.